# Confusion regarding TopoJSON polygon coordinates

Tags: polygon, mapping, topojson

I have a TopoJSON file which represents a hexagon. A hexagon has 6 vertices, so I was expecting the `arcs` attribute of TopoJSON file would contain 6 points, but it contains 7.

I wanted to know why there are 7 coordinates instead of 6, and what does that extra coordinate represent?

```
{   "type": "Topology",   "arcs": [
    [
      [
        0,
        1
      ],
      [
        0.5,
        0.86
      ],
      [
        0.5,
        -0.86
      ],
      [
        0,
        -1
      ],
      [
        -0.5,
        -0.86
      ],
      [
        -0.5,
        0.86
      ],
      [
        0,
        1
      ]
    ]   ],   "transform": {
    "scale": [
      1,
      0.5
    ],
    "translate": [
      0,
      0
    ]   },   "objects": {
    "state": {
      "type": "GeometryCollection",
      "geometries": [
        {
          "arcs": [
            [
              0
            ]
          ],
          "type": "Polygon",
          "id": "A&N ISLANDS"
        }
      ]
    }   } }
```

Answer (score 1):

The 1st and last vertices of a closed polygon are always the same, so a triangle is defined by 4 points

Comment: To give some reference to this answer https://github.com/topojson/topojson-specification#225-polygon (The TopoJSON Format Specification)

Comment: Thanks @J.R . Let's note that this convention is largely adopted in other data formats as well

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have another topojson file where the first and the last point of the Polygon is not same. File Link: https://github.com/info-design-lab/election2019/blob/gh-pages/map/cartogram/ARUNACHAL%20PRADESH.json

Comment: @ArihantParsoya That other file is GeoJSON, not TopoJSON